# pyqt - prevent requests for images and javascript files

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am loading some html into a pyqt by doing:

```
    view = QWebView()
    view.setHtml(html)
```

If the html has script or img tags with "src" pointing to remote resources then these will be requested.

I would like to prevent these requests.

I can use maybe beautifulsoup to remove such tags in the html, but is there a built in pyqt way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyQt being just a wrapper around Qt, the solution is to be looked for in Qt itself.
I am not an expert of the web widgets, but I know that a `QWebView` is configured with [QWebSettings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebsettings.html), which you can use to disable javascript and the automatic loading of images. However this does not solve the problem for stylesheets and other external files.

To prevent *any* external request, one solution you can try is to use the [QNetworkAccessManager](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html). This is the class that is the entry point to all network accesses done by the web page. You can set a [property `networkAccessible`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#networkAccessible-prop) on an instance of this class that "disable" the network, which will prevent all network requests. You have of course to set that property *before* the page is loaded.

Translated into code:

```
view = QWebView()
netmanager = view.page().networkAccessManager()
netmanager.setNetworkAccessible(QNetworkAccessManager.NotAccessible)
view.setHtml(html)
```